# Debugging C++ app in Visual Studio 2017 steps into not my code. Is there a way to turn this off?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok so when debugging, for example when I set my breakpoint on simple string declaration

```
string a;
```

and then pressing f11 (step into) my debugger steps into `xstring` file, and I don't want it. I want it to step into JUST MY code. This works fine with C# projects, but not with C++ ones.

How I defined it for C++ projects in Visual Studio:
[image: C++]

How I use it in C#, where it works well:
[image: C# and what I want it to be in C++ also]

I have "Just My Code" enabled and I don't know what to do. I just dont want it to step in not my files.

Comment: What about not pressing "step into", but pressing "step over"?

Comment: When you press "step into" you *step into* the `std::string` constructor function. Just like "step into" is *supposed* to do.

Comment: Then it steps over my function and i want it to step into my functions but JUST my functions for example in
    p0->fork("p1");
it will step into xstring and i want it to just step into Process fork function which i implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# feature you are referring to is called "Just My Code". Unfortunately, Visual Studio does not implement it in the same way for C++. As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code) says:

> C++ Just My Code is different than .NET Framework and JavaScript Just
>   My Code because the stepping behavior is independent of the call stack
>   behavior.

There is a workaround, however:

> You can create your own `.natstepfilter` and `.natjmc` to customize the
>   stepping and call stack window behavior in the `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Visualizers`.

Despite of the typo in the documentation ("2015") and the horribly convoluted way this was designed, the trick actually works!

For example, with the Visual Studio 2017 installation on my machine, I can go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` and a add file called `.natstepfilter` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<StepFilter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natstepfilter/2010">  
    <Function>  
        <Name>std::.*</Name>  
        <Action>NoStepInto</Action>  
    </Function>  
</StepFilter>
```

Now when I debug in Visual Studio and *step into* something, all C++ standard-library functions are skipped.

Note that the actual format of the XML file is not validated very strictly by Visual Studio. I've actually used the simpler form explained in the [Visual Studio 2015 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8 is shipped with an improved support of "Just My Code" for C++ projects, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022):

> Starting in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8, Just My Code for code stepping is also supported. This feature also requires use of the /JMC (Just my code debugging) compiler switch. The switch is enabled by default in C++ projects. For Call Stack window and call stack support in Just My Code, the /JMC switch is not required.

Hence the `\JMC` compiler switch needs to be set for all own C++ projects in the Debug configuration:

[image: Sample picture of compiler settings for Debug configuration]

Tested with Visual Studio 2022, this compiler switch works really well and no `.natstepfilter` is required anymore to step over the `std::.*` stuff.