# Force Visual Studio to Step Into STL classes/functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, stl, visual-studio-2019

Lets assume we have this code snippet

```cpp
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> a = { 1,2 };
        a.push_back(3);
        return 0;
    }
```

In VS 2019 I am attempting to Step Into (F11) the `constructor` and `push_back` function, but VS simply steps over it.

There are other solutions like [Debugging C++ app in Visual Studio 2017 steps into not my code is there a way to turn this off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489372/debugging-c-app-in-visual-studio-2017-steps-into-not-my-code-is-there-a-way-to) or [Skip STL Code when debugging C++ Code in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352426/skip-stl-code-when-debugging-c-code-in-visual-studio-2012), which actually ask for the opposite (turn step into off). So I tried to reverse their solutions, e.g. adding
`<Function><Name>std::.*</Name><Action>StepInto</Action></Function>` in
`C:\...\Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter`
but it doesn't work.

I am running `Debug x64` with these options
`/JMC /permissive- /GS /W4 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\EnvTest.pch" /diagnostics:column`

What's the right setting to force VS to step into STL classes/functions?

Comment: Are you running a debug build or an optimized build? Most accessors are optimized out in optimized builds.

Comment: Added the options/build i am using

Comment: Please call it C++ Standard library, not STL.

Comment: Turn off: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > __[X] Enable Just My Code__   This is not a build/project setting but an IDE option.  With this option on you will step over all the standard library code.

Comment: @RichardCritten This helped indeed. Happy to accept it as an answer, if posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn off: Tools > Options > Debugging > General > **[X] Enable Just My Code**.

This is not a build/project setting but an IDE option. With this option on you will step over all the standard library code.

Comment: I have Enable Just My Code ticked and Visual Studio steps into the std code when I do step in.